# How to run VMware commands from remote scripts on windows

Tags: powershell, vmware, powercli

Have a local basic `Powershell` form for searching and creating VMware virtual machines.

Using new `powershell` powerCLI module, as described in [link](https://blogs.vmware.com/PowerCLI/2017/04/powercli-install-process-powershell-gallery.html)

Let's take `Get-VM` for example:

LOGIC: Type a certain string in `TextBox`  > click `search` > prints VM's status/parameters in the form

The problem is, I can't execute `Get-VM` straight away from the script, but first have to connect using `Connect-VIServer` command and only than `Get-VM` will work

Is there any way to do it from the script? Something similar to `-m` flag of commands `plink` or `putty`.

Like: `Connect-VIServer -server testvc -flagForExample "commands_list.txt"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can. Before providing an immediate answer I'd like to explain what is actually happening.
When you call `Connect-VIServer` the command sets the value of the variable `$DefaultVIServer` behind the scenes, which is later used by other cmdlets (such as `Get-VM`).

However, the [Get-VM documentation](https://www.vmware.com/support/developer/PowerCLI/PowerCLI41U1/html/Get-VM.html) states that there is a `Server` parameter available. Which means that you can store your server connection in a variable and then pass it to the `Get-VM` cmdlet.

Here's a pseudo-code example:

`$server = Connect-VIServer -server testvc
Get-VM -Server $server`

Furthermore, the `Get-VM` supports an array of servers, so theoretically you can run the cmdlet on multiple servers at once. For example:

`$server1 = Connect-VIServer -server testvc
$server2 = Connect-VIServer -server testvc2
Get-VM -Server @($server1, $server2)`

Comment: Thanks, it works as expected. Have a little problem with the output, executing as you said and then doing `$test=@(Get-VM -Server $server -Name vmName|out-string)` but all tabs and spaces are messed up, not like in powershell terminal. Do you know why?

Comment: You're grabbing the output. Instead, do:`Get-VM -Server $server -Name vmName | Select-Object Property1,Property2 | Out-String` replacing properties with the property results you want to print.

Comment: Weird, there is a big difference between outputs. I don't think this is a good solution, because I need to do it for each VMware command

Comment: @igor then run the commands in the cycle, put the results into an array and output: `$results = @(); $results += Get-VM; $results += Get-VM; $results | Out-String`